How to uninstall or totally disable seahorse/gnome-keyring
I log in into system using authentication token, thus I don't type in password. This does not unlock gnome-keyring/seahorse, and at first attempt it requires me to type password. Yes, there is possibility to enter empty password for keyring, and in that case gnome-keyring will not require password — for a week. For some reason, somehow, this regularly resets, and while I setup empty password at least 10 times, the prompts are still coming back.
How go get rid of this thing entirely? If I try apt remove gnome-keyring it will cascade to remove whole desktop environment.
